# Why there is no GroupBy clause in internal SQL of Entity Framework linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, group-by, entity-framework-6

In documentation of Entity Framework:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx

in section regarding GroupBy we can read that following code:

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{    
    var students = from s in ctx.Students 
                group s by s.StandardId into studentsByStandard
                select studentsByStandard;

    foreach (var groupItem in students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(groupItem.Key);

        foreach (var stud in groupItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stud.StudentId);
        }
    }
}
```

executes internally following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[StandardId] AS [StandardId], 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project2].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
[Project2].[StudentName] AS [StudentName], 
[Project2].[StandardId1] AS [StandardId1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[StandardId] AS [StandardId], 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
    [Extent2].[StudentName] AS [StudentName], 
    [Extent2].[StandardId] AS [StandardId1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[StudentID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[StandardId] AS [StandardId]
        FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Distinct1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent2] ON ([Distinct1].[StandardId] = [Extent2].                                                [StandardId]) OR (([Distinct1].[StandardId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[StandardId] IS NULL))
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[StandardId] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
go
```

Why there is no GroupBy clause in SQL? If there is no GroupBy clause needed, can’t we just use simple Select with OrderBy and without Joins? Can anyone explain the above query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom line is: because SQL can't return nested result sets.

Every SQL `SELECT` statement returns a flat list of values. LINQ is capable of returning object graphs, i.e. objects with nested objects. That's exactly what LINQ's `GroupBy` does.

In SQL, a `GROUP BY` statement only returns the grouping columns and aggregate results:

```sql
SELECT StandardId, COUNT(*)
FROM Students
GROUP BY StandardId;
```

The rest of the student columns is gone.

A LINQ `GroupBy` statement returns something like

```
StandardId
            StudentId StudentName
1
            21        "Student1"
            15        "Student2"
2
            48        "Student3"
            91        "Student4"
            17        "Student5"
```

Therefore, a SQL `GROUP BY` statement can never be the source for a LINQ `GroupBy`.

Entity Framework (6) knows this and it generates a SQL statement that pulls all required data from the database, adds some parts that make grouping easier, and it creates the groupings client-side.

Comment: But why can't we make just a simple Select without Joins and with OrderBy?

Comment: Because "we" don't do anything :). It's EF's decision to create this kind of query, I think because it guarantees that groups can be created client-side.